# Swift delegates - Newbie 3 ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

So here is my problem.
I started my journey with Swift and C# and I'm trying to learn delegates in the most simple way possible.

I created a xcode project where I set up 3 view Controllers.
I created 2 segues:

1. I can go from firstViewController (firstVC) to secondViewController (secondVC)
2. I can go from firstViewController to thirdViewController (thirdVC)

App purposes:

1. Go from firstVC to secondVC, tap one button, dissmis the view and update the label based on the tapped button. -- This one was easy.
2. Go from first VC to thirdVC, tap the only button there, dissmis the view and update the same label as previously with some simple text -- This one was done too.
3. If I tap the button in thirdVC I want to change label in the secondVC

The third one is not that easy for me.

Code below:

FirstViewController:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, SecondViewControllerDelegate, ThirdViewControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var answerLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "firstToSecondSegue" {
        let secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
        secondVC.delegate = self
    } else if segue.identifier == "firstToThirdSegue" {
        let thirdVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ThirdViewController
        thirdVC.delegate = self
    }
}

@IBAction func answerButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 0 {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("firstToSecondSegue", sender: self)
    } else if sender.tag == 1 {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("firstToThirdSegue", sender: self)
    }
}

func giveTheAnswer(yes: Bool) {
    if yes {
        print("Yes is the answer")
        self.answerLabel.text = "I do like chicken!"
    } else {
        print("No is the answer")
        self.answerLabel.text = "I do not like chicken!"
    }
}

func iWantPie(kindOfPie: String, disableButton: Bool) {
    if kindOfPie == "Apple pie" {
        print("Textlabel will change to applepie.")
        self.answerLabel.text = "Fu*k chicken. Let's eat apple pie!"
    }
    if disableButton {
        print("DisableButton set to true")
        self.answerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
}
```

SecondViewController:

```
protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate {
func giveTheAnswer(yes: Bool)}


class SecondViewController: UIViewController, ThirdViewControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var theOnlyLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var yesButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var noButton: UIButton!

var delegate: SecondViewControllerDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func answerButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.tag == 0 {
        //Yes tapped
        self.delegate?.giveTheAnswer(true)
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    } else if sender.tag == 1 {
        //No Tapped
        self.delegate?.giveTheAnswer(false)
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func iWantPie(kindOfPie: String, disableButton: Bool) {
    print("Function iWantPie in secondViewController is Running")
    if disableButton == true {
        print("DisableButton running")
        self.theOnlyLabel.text = "Pie was tapped"
    }

}}
```

ThirdViewController:

```
protocol ThirdViewControllerDelegate {
func iWantPie(kindOfPie: String, disableButton: Bool)}

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

var delegate: ThirdViewControllerDelegate?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()    

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func piePressed(sender: UIButton) {
    self.delegate?.iWantPie("Apple pie", disableButton: true)
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}}
```

Comment: Hey with your flow I don't see that SeconVC and ThirdVC existing at the same time?

Comment: Mean u want to press the btn in 3rd, then back to 1st then go to 2nd and see the change? If yes then the flow is just the same, but at 1st u don't update anything but pass it to 2nd, u cant really call the 2nd delegate since its not initialized if u don't go to 3rd from 2nd

Comment: exactly as pointed out by @view vu I don't see a possibility of having second and third VC in the segue stack. You either go from 1->2 or 1->3, is there any other segue than those you have mentioned in the code?

Comment: There is no Objective-C in this example. Can you remove the Objective-C tag?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the below code is working or not by adding a break point in the if else conditions.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "firstToSecondSegue" {
        let secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
        secondVC.delegate = self
    } else if segue.identifier == "firstToThirdSegue" {
        let thirdVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ThirdViewController
        thirdVC.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Also check if you have given the correct segue identifiers to the segue in the storyboard.
"firstToSecondSegue"  and "firstToThirdSegue"

Comment: It is running. I mean:

SecondVC is connected to FirstVC, and ThirdVC is also connected to FirstVC.

But how to connect ThirdVC to SecondVC without the need to create segue between them?